# Android Error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil

Tags: android, google-maps, import, android-gradle-plugin

I am currently creating an application that draws a overlay onto a google map, between to points. I can select the two points but then the app will crash at this stage giving the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil
```

I have imported the SphericalUtil to the class and added the

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
```

to the dependencies in the gradle

Error

```
    04-24 13:49:16.127 25993-25993/com.example.runnable E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.runnable, PID: 25993
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil
    at com.example.runnable.MapCal.drawPath(MapCal.java:242)
    at com.example.runnable.MapCal$1.onResponse(MapCal.java:220)
    at com.example.runnable.MapCal$1.onResponse(MapCal.java:215)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
     at 

 com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
  at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.21.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'


    //compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here is main body code

```
package com.example.runnable;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MapCal extends Fragment implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    //Our Map
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    //To store longitude and latitude from map
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    //From -> the first coordinate from where we need to calculate the distance
    private double fromLongitude;
    private double fromLatitude;

    //To -> the second coordinate to where we need to calculate the distance
    private double toLongitude;
    private double toLatitude;

    //Google ApiClient
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    //Our buttons
    private Button buttonSetTo;
    private Button buttonSetFrom;
    private Button buttonCalcDistance;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapcal, container, false);


        if (!SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).isLoggedIn()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class));
        }


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);


        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

        buttonSetTo = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSetTo);
        buttonSetFrom = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSetFrom);
        buttonCalcDistance = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCalcDistance);

        buttonSetTo.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonSetFrom.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonCalcDistance.setOnClickListener(this);







        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setTitle("Directions");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();

    }

    //Getting current location
    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        mMap.clear();
        //Creating a location object
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            //Getting longitude and latitude
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            //moving the map to location
            moveMap();
        }
    }

    //Function to move the map
    private void moveMap() {
        //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates





        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        //Adding marker to map
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng) //setting position
                .draggable(true) //Making the marker draggable
                .title("Current Location")); //Adding a title

        //Moving the camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        //Animating the camera
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }

    public String makeURL (double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat, double destlog ){
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
        urlString.append("?origin=");// from
        urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString
                .append(Double.toString( sourcelog));
        urlString.append("&destination=");// to
        urlString
                .append(Double.toString( destlat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(destlog));
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
        urlString.append("&key=AIzaSyBAaPwU27UCksaRKJ-nehOC-fGizciCsAs");
        return urlString.toString();
    }

    private void getDirection(){
        //Getting the URL
        String url = makeURL(fromLatitude, fromLongitude, toLatitude, toLongitude);

        //Showing a dialog till we get the route
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Getting Route", "Please wait...", false, false);

        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        //Calling the method drawPath to draw the path
                        drawPath(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        //Adding the request to request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    //The parameter is the server response
    public void drawPath(String  result) {
        //Getting both the coordinates
        LatLng from = new LatLng(fromLatitude,fromLongitude);
        LatLng to = new LatLng(toLatitude,toLongitude);

        //Calculating the distance in meters
        Double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(from, to);

        //Displaying the distance
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.valueOf(distance+" Meters"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        try {
            //Parsing json
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);
            Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .addAll(list)
                    .width(10)
                    .color(Color.BLUE)
                    .geodesic(true)
            );


        }
        catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng( (((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5) ));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
       // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(54.607868, -5.926437)).title("Marker"));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        getCurrentLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        //Clearing all the markers
        mMap.clear();
        //Adding a new marker to the current pressed position
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true));

        latitude = latLng.latitude;
        longitude = latLng.longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        //Getting the coordinates
        latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

        //Moving the map
        moveMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonSetFrom){
            fromLatitude = latitude;
            fromLongitude = longitude;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Start Location Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(v == buttonSetTo){
            toLatitude = latitude;
            toLongitude = longitude;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Final Destination Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(v == buttonCalcDistance){
            getDirection();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `android:android-maps-utils:0.5+`

Comment: That change still produced the same error message

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link to solve your problem

Reference -http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/

See link here:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java

Comment: Please add some details

Comment: This wasnt able to help me, this build had previously worked on another android phone, but crashes on another

Comment: Have you checked OS version for both phone.Is that same?

Comment: I think there is some class is missing in Android 4.4.2 which is available in Android 6.0.Try to implement with this fresh code for 4.4.2 with the help of this link...https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/setup